# Concurrent tasks on a Spark executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What determines how many tasks can run concurrently on a Spark executor? Maybe it is some kind of thread pool and shared memory resources?

What parameters control that behavior?

Does it mean that code used in executors should always be written thread-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What determines how many tasks can run concurrently on a Spark executor?

Spark maps the number tasks on a particular Executor to the number of cores allocated to it. By default, Spark assigns one core to a task which is controlled by the `spark.task.cpus` parameter which defaults to 1.

> Does it mean that code used in executors should always be written thread-safe?

No. Generally working with RDDs or DataFrame/Set is aimed so you do work locally inside a transform, without sharing global resources. You should think about thread-safety when you have a global resource which would execute in parallel inside a single Executor process, which can happen when multiple tasks are executed on the same Executor.

Comment: So that means, if we do have shared variables, we have to be concerned. Would it be acceptable to have on an executor: a synchronized block for creation of some shared (across tasks/threads) variables (later to be used only as read-only)?

Comment: @DruckerBg If initialization can happen concurrently, consider using a `lazy val`.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant parameter to control parallel execution are:

`spark.executor.instances` -> number of executors

`spark.executor.cores` ->  number of cores per executors

`spark.task.cpus` -> number of tasks per cpu

But having multiple tasks in parallel does not mean you need thread-safe code, because these tasks are independent of each other (they don't share variables)